# How to hide multiple columns in multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am going through 25 workbooks in a specific directory and need to hide the same columns in each workbook.

I've set the code up so that it cycles through each workbook, but it fails when it comes to the hiding of the columns. I've done the googling, but am missing something.

The specific code that isn't working:

```
Worksheets("Ops1").Range("F:AE,AG:AQ,AS:CP,CW:EF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Worksheets("Ops2").Range("F:AE,AG:AQ,AS:CP,CW:EF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

And the whole thing:

```
 Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                 'your code here
                 Worksheets("Ops1").Range("F:AE,AG:AQ,AS:CP,CW:EF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Worksheets("Ops2").Range("F:AE,AG:AQ,AS:CP,CW:EF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End With
        xFileName = Dir
        Loop
   End If
```

I receive a **runtime error code '9' subscript out of range**.

Comment: `.Worksheets("Ops1").Range("F:AE,AG:AQ,AS:CP,CW:EF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`  missing the leading period before `Worksheets`

Answer (score 1):

You can try seting the range to a variable like this.

```vb
Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim sht1ColumnsToHide As Range
    Dim sht2ColumnsToHide As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheet("Ops1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheet("Ops2")
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                 'your code here
                    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Ops1")
                    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Ops2")

                 With ws1
                 Set sht1ColumnsToHide = Application.Union(.Columns("F:AE"), _
                                            .Columns("AG:AQ"), _
                                            .Columns("AS:CP"), _
                                            .Columns("CW:EF"))
                 sht1ColumnsToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 End With

                 With ws2
                 Set sht2ColumnsToHide = Application.Union(.Columns("F:AE"), _
                                            .Columns("AG:AQ"), _
                                            .Columns("AS:CP"), _
                                            .Columns("CW:EF"))
                 sht2ColumnsToHide.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
               End With
            End With
        xFileName = Dir
        Loop
   End If
```

Comment: you would need to set the sheets variables in the loop after opening the workbook (in the `With` statement), and use `.Worksheets...` (note the `s`). Other than that, is working as intended.

Comment: @DarXyde your right complete missed that always in the bad habit to dim and set at the top. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Can be streamlined a bit better, but this should do the trick. Just reusing your code:

```vb
Dim xFd As FileDialog
Dim xFdItem As Variant
Dim xFileName As String
Dim X As Long, C As Long, lCol As Long
Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & ".xls")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                'not sure if all your sheets are called OpsX, might need to change this
                For X = 1 To 2  'Loop through all the sheets
                    With .Worksheets("Ops" & X) 'Note the use of <[ . ]> (DOT) in the With statement
                        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'Get the last column, relative to row 1

                        For C = lCol To 1 Step -1           'Loop through all columns, starting at last one
                            Select Case C
                                Case 5 To 31 'F:AE
                                   .Cells(1, C).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                                Case 33 To 43 'AG:AQ
                                   .Cells(1, C).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                                Case 45 To 94 'AS:CP
                                   .Cells(1, C).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                                Case 101 To 136 'CW:EF
                                   .Cells(1, C).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                            End Select
                        Next C
                    End With
                Next X
            End With
        xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: You can set `Application.Union` and then use the variable to hide all in one go without the need for case statement or looping through the columns.

Comment: @QuickSilver I've seen your response, and although I'm not particularly familiar with the union function in VBA, I can see how this is a good scenario to use it. However if later you need to introduce some additional conditions before hiding certain columns or add more sheets in the mix, a `loop`/`select case` as the above is a better solution, as would require minimal code change/addition.

Comment: you are absolutely right in that aspect. I guess it depends on the data you are having and if that is likely to change over time.